# Не могу записать корректно данные в бинарный файл

Tags: c#, .net

Ошибка "Необработанное исключение: System.IO.EndOfStreamException: невозможно прочитать данные за пределами конца потока." Ошибка возникает в LoadTeachers()" в фрагменте teacher.Name
Сохранение

```
   string path = "Teachers.bin";
    public void SaveTeachers(List<Teacher> teachers)
    {
        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(path)))
        {
            foreach (Teacher teacher in teachers)
            {
                bw.Write(teacher.Id);
                bw.Write(teacher.Surname);
                bw.Write(teacher.Name);
                bw.Write(teacher.Middlename);
                bw.Write(teacher.YearOfTheBirth);
                bw.Write(teacher.Disciplines.Length);
                for (int i = 0; i < teacher.Disciplines.Length; i++)
                    bw.Write(teacher.Disciplines[i]);
                bw.Write(teacher.Groups.Length);
                for (int i = 0; i < teacher.Groups.Length; i++)
                    bw.Write(teacher.Groups[i]);
                bw.Write(teacher.Login);
                bw.Write(teacher.Password);
            }
        }
    }
```

Загрузка данных с файла

```
 public List<Teacher> LoadTeachers()
    {
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead("Teachers.bin")))
        {
            List<Teacher> teachers = new List<Teacher>();
            while (br.PeekChar() > -1)
            {
                Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
                teacher.Id = br.ReadInt32();
                teacher.Surname = br.ReadString();
                teacher.Name = br.ReadString();
                teacher.Middlename = br.ReadString();
                teacher.YearOfTheBirth = br.ReadInt32();
                teacher.Disciplines = new string[br.ReadInt32()];
                for (int i = 0; i < teacher.Disciplines.Length; i++)
                    teacher.Disciplines[i] = br.ReadString();
                teacher.Groups = new string[br.ReadInt32()];
                for (int i = 0; i < teacher.Groups.Length; i++)
                    teacher.Groups[i] = br.ReadString();
                teacher.Login = br.ReadString();
                teacher.Password = br.ReadString();
                teachers.Add(teacher);
            }
            return teachers;
        }
    }
```

Вызов

```
Teacher t = new Teacher();
        t.SetAll();
        List<Teacher> teachers = new List<Teacher>();
        teachers.Add(new Teacher
        {
            Id = t.Id,
            Surname = t.Surname,
            Name = t.Name,
            Middlename = t.Middlename,
            YearOfTheBirth = t.YearOfTheBirth,
            Disciplines = t.Disciplines,
            Groups = t.Groups,
            Login = t.Login,
            Password = t.Password
        });

        t.SaveTeachers(teachers);
        List<Teacher> loadedTeachers = t.LoadTeachers();
        foreach (Teacher teacher in loadedTeachers)
            Console.WriteLine(teacher);
```

Comment: Когда вместо File.OpenWrite(path) пишет File.Сreate(path) то все нормально работает но мне нада дописывать данные в файл а не создавать новый

Comment: У вас проблема не с записью, а с чтением. Вы пытаетесь читать из потока, который уже кончился.

Comment: я знаю и от мне нужно сделать нормальную запись что-бы такого не было т.к. при File.Сreate(path) все норм работает но проблема в том что мне нужно записывать новые данные в файл

Comment: ну так пользуйтесь двоичной сериализацией. В дотнете для этого есть класс [BinaryFormatter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нужно было использовать FileStream

```
 using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)))

using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)))
```

Comment: Обязательно оберните каждый FileStream в оператор `using`!

Answer (score 2):

Метод `File.OpenWrite` открывает файл и помещает указатель в **начало** потока. Таким образом при записи вы затираете ранее записанные данные.

При этом, если раньше данных было больше, чем записано теперь, то кусок старых данных остаётся в файле. И метод `PeekChar`, дойдя до этих данных, обнаруживает их. В итоге методы `ReadInt32`, `ReadString` пытаются их читать. Отсюда и ошибки.

Вы хотите дописывать в файл, значит нужно установить указатель в **конец** потока.

```
using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(path))
{
    fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
    using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

`FileStream` нужно обязательно диспозить (освобождать), поэтому нужно заключить его в `using`. Сделайте это и в методе чтения:

```
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(path))
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
{
    ....
}
```

---

Можно использовать метод `File.Open`, в котором можно указать параметр `FileMode.Append` - это автоматически установит указатель в конец потока. И делать `Seek` вручную уже не нужно.

```
using (var fileStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Append))
using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
{
    ...
}
```

При этом желательно задать и другие параметры: `FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None` - тогда поток будет в точности соответствовать тому, который возвращается методом `File.OpenWrite`.